# NUnit runner failure when running IE tests in TeamCity

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, teamcity, nunit-3.0

My devops team helped me move my tests to our TeamCity server yesterday. I was running the tests and was noticing that TC was having troubles running the IE tests. Both the chrome and Firefox tests ran fine, but IE failed to get past the `[OneTimeSetUp]`I modified my tests to only run in IE to try and debug this issue, and added some logging to my `[OneTimeSetUp]` here is the build log from my last run. Oh and when I run test locally both through Visual Studio, and the Nunit3 Console runner they work as expected. It only seems to be an issue on the server.

```
[08:45:16]Collecting changes in 2 VCS roots (3s)
[08:45:22]Read build settings from revision 4292e99b99139f5690d76975027f7dcd27be7b1c
[08:45:28]Skip checking for changes - changes are already collected
[08:45:28]Clearing temporary directory: C:\TCAgents\1\temp\buildTmp
[08:45:28]Failed to delete file: C:\TCAgents\1\temp\buildTmp\IED2D56.tmp
[08:45:28]Unable to cleanup build temporary directory: C:\TCAgents\1\temp\buildTmp
[08:45:28]Publishing internal artifacts
[08:45:28]Checkout directory: C:\TCAgents\1\work\dace7211e88930a1
[08:45:28]Updating sources: server side checkout
[08:45:29]Step 1/4: NuGet Installer (12s)
[08:45:41]Step 2/4: MSBuild (13s)
[08:45:55]Step 3/4: Command Line
[08:45:55]Step 4/4: NUnit (13m:43s)
[08:45:55][Step 4/4] Starting: C:\TCAgents\1\work\dace7211e88930a1\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.2.1\tools\nunit-console.exe C:\TCAgents\1\temp\buildTmp\VOeQiCSDUHkfkJI0vuoLGqxn8BI3wxbu.nunit --work=C:\TCAgents\1\work\dace7211e88930a1 --noresult --noheader
[08:45:55][Step 4/4] in directory: C:\TCAgents\1\work\dace7211e88930a1
[08:45:57][Step 4/4] Runtime Environment
[08:45:57][Step 4/4]    OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
[08:45:57][Step 4/4]   CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000
[08:45:57][Step 4/4] 
[08:45:57][Step 4/4] Test Files
[08:45:57][Step 4/4]     C:\TCAgents\1\temp\buildTmp\VOeQiCSDUHkfkJI0vuoLGqxn8BI3wxbu.nunit
[08:45:57][Step 4/4] 
[08:45:59][Step 4/4] POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.dll (running for 13m:39s)
[08:46:01][Step 4/4] Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
[08:46:01][Step 4/4] 2.53.0.0
[08:46:01][Step 4/4] Listening on port 63290
[08:46:01][Step 4/4] Only local connections are allowed
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:29][Step 4/4] OneTimeSetUp: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException : A generic error occurred in GDI+.
[08:49:30][Step 4/4] => POMAuctivaTest.TestSuite.ExistingUserTestSuite<InternetExplorerDriver>
[08:49:30][Step 4/4] 2016-05-12 08:46:05,212 INFO ExistingUserTest - On the homepage durring setup. 
[08:49:30][Step 4/4] 2016-05-12 08:46:11,190 INFO ExistingUserTest - Logged in to account.
[08:49:30][Step 4/4] Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
[08:49:30][Step 4/4] 2.53.0.0
[08:49:30][Step 4/4] Listening on port 63658
[08:49:30][Step 4/4] Only local connections are allowed
[08:52:53][Step 4/4] Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
[08:52:53][Step 4/4] 2.53.0.0
[08:52:53][Step 4/4] Listening on port 63998
[08:52:53][Step 4/4] Only local connections are allowed
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] 
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] Errors and Failures
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] 
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] 1) Error : C:\TCAgents\1\temp\buildTmp\VOeQiCSDUHkfkJI0vuoLGqxn8BI3wxbu.nunit
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] 
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] Server stack trace: 
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityAttributes)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at NUnit.Engine.Drivers.NUnit3FrameworkDriver.Run(ITestEventListener listener, String filter)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.DirectTestRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] 
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] Exception rethrown at [0]: 
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at NUnit.Engine.ITestEngineRunner.Run(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]    at NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests(ITestEventListener listener, TestFilter filter)
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] 
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] Test Run Summary
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]   Overall result: Failed
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]   Test Count: 0, Passed: 0, Failed: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]   Start time: 2016-05-12 15:45:59Z
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]     End time: 2016-05-12 15:59:39Z
[08:59:39][Step 4/4]     Duration: 819.286 seconds
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] 
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] Process exited with code -100
[08:59:39][Step 4/4] Step NUnit failed
[08:59:39]Publishing artifacts
[08:59:39]Publishing internal artifacts
[08:59:39]Build finished
```

Comment: I found it interesting that there is an almost 7 minute gap in there where I'm assuming it's not running any tests? Is it possible to RDP to the Build agent server (if it's not the same as the TeamCity server) and run the tests with the console runner there, try to get a visual and see if IE is hanging up on something?

Comment: There's not a proxy server that InternetExplorer is picking up that Firefox/Chrome are ignoring is there?  Also, is your process 64 bit?  You might need to invoke the 64 bit InternetExplorer as opposed to the 32 bit instance.  And yes, there's a difference for IE.

Comment: So I confirmed with DevOps that the server is running a 64 bit version of windows server. So I had a 32 bit version of InternetExplorerDriver. I changed it out for the 64 bit version (https://github.com/cchitsiang/nuget-selenium-webdriver-iedriver64) but am still seeing build logs that say 

`Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)`